# Anti-Affinity Rules not Enabling in vCenter 6.0

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, rules, affinity

Can anyone please help.  I am building a new vCenter with 3 hosts, all running VMWare ESXi 6.0.
I currently have about 16-18 VMs created.
I have been able to create a number of Affinity and Anti-Affinity rules so far but one rule is just failing to enable.
It is an Anti-Affinity rule to keep 2 VMs apart.  These two VMs are not included in any other rule.
I can tick the box to enable the rule but when I click OK, the Edit Settings box disappears.  When I next look in there, this one rule is unticked again.

It would appear that any rule one specific VM is in, will fail to enable but I cannot see anything on the VM that could cause this.  Both VMs appear to be built and configured the same.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can try?

Comment: Happy to help but you need to show us as much detail of what you've got now for us to help please.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this forum... What information do you need?  My problem is that I am not sure if the issue lies with the VM or the vCenter.
Thanks.

Comment: a) it's not a forum, we hate it being called that :), b) it's almost certainly not a VM issue, it'll be vCenter config - so show us screen-grabs of the cluster config, specifically the DRS groups and rules please